# DB Connect and workspace notebooks returns different results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect, dbconnect

I'm using DB Connect 9.1.9.
My cluster version is 9.1LTS with a single node (for test purposes).

My data is stored on a S3 as a delta table.

Running the following:

```
df = spark.sql("select * from <table_name> where runDate >= '2022-01-10 14:00:00' and runDate <= '2022-01-10 15:00:00'")
```

When I run it with DB Connect I get: 31.
When I run it on a Databricks Workspace: 462.

Of course you can't check that numbers, I just wanted to find why do we have a difference.

If I remove the condition on the runDate, I have good results on both platform.
So I deduced that it was the "runDate" fault, but I can't find why.

The schema:

```
StructType(List(StructField(id,StringType,False), 
                StructField(runDate,TimestampType,true)))
```

I have the same explain plan on both platform too.

Did I miss something about Timestamp usage ?

Update 1: it is funny, when I'm putting the count() inside the `spark.sql("SELECT count(*) ...")` directly I still have 31 rows. It might be the way db-connect translate the query to the cluster.

Comment: are you sure that you don't have a copy of data on your local machine?

Comment: How could I have a copy data using the spark.sql API ? And it works when I remove the date filter.

Comment: @AlexOtt it was the timezone associated to the spark session. May we have some documentation in the troubleshooting part of databricks connect (https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#troubleshooting) ?

Comment: it's more a general Spark debugging piece...

Comment: yep I understand, but since we don't handle this on Databricks side (with notebooks), it can be hard to debug in my opinion when you swap to db-connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the timezone associated to the Spark Session.

Add this after your spark session declaration (in case your dates are stored in UTC):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```